# Vim: Edit files on FTP server over Passive (PASV) mode

Tags: vim, ftp, netrw, passive-mode

I need to access a server using an FTP client in passive mode, but how do I do this for Vim FTP 
connections?

Running `ftp -p 12.34.56.67` works fine, but how do I do this when starting vim (for ex. `vim ftp://12.34.56.78/`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://alecthegeek.github.io/2007/02/06/handy-hack-how-to-use-vim-netrw-in-ftp-passive-mode.html) article states that you need to add this line to your `.vimrc`:

```
let g:netrw_ftp_cmd="ftp -p"
```

After that, according to [this](https://www.marksanborn.net/software/modify-remote-files-with-vims-built-in-ftp-plugin/) article, you should be able to do:

```
vim ftp://username@yourdomain.com//the/path/to/yourfile.php
```

This seems to be a native Vim function.

**Note:** This option should be turned off for FTP servers that are not passive.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for explicit TLS/PASV mode

Comment: I edited my answer, does that work for you @Ben?

Comment: No problem, have a good day! :)

Comment: Dead link. Update: https://web.archive.org/web/20201221125657/https://alecthegeek.github.io/2007/02/06/handy-hack-how-to-use-vim-netrw-in-ftp-passive-mode.html (edit queue full).